# ArrayList not adding elements

Tags: java

My array list is supposed to have a line of asterisk before and after each occurrence of the smallest number in it. I have debugged and all variables are holding the correct values but for some reason it wont add the values.

Here is my code:

```
int smallest = array[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
            if (array[i] < smallest) 
                smallest = array[i];

                String smallestString = String.valueOf(smallest);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0;i < size; i++)
            list.add(Integer.toString(array[i]));


        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        if (smallestString.equals(list.get(i))) {
            list.add(i, "*****"); 
            list.add(i + 2, "*****");
        }

            System.out.println("\n" + list);

            return smallest;
```

Comment: Try delimiting your loops with `{` `}` blocks, it will be less error-prone .

Comment: Note that if you iterate from front to back you'll have to take bigger steps since adding elements will shift everything after the current element to the right, i.e. if your list is `1,2,3` then adding `*` at index 0 and 2 will result in `*,1,*,2,3` and the next element (`2`) is now to be found at index 3.

Comment: @Thomas Thats why I added 2 when I add the second line of asterisk.

Comment: @Berger I only dont use `{` `}` blocks when there is one line to loop

Comment: Lack of braces and messed up indentation are a horrible combination. Your code is needlessly confusing.

Comment: See my expanded comment for what I mean. Also your loop is bound to be endless since you increment `i` by 1 but add elements inside the loop thus the list's size might increase with every iteration if the condition is met.

Comment: So how would I account for that in the loop?

Comment: There are a few ways, e.g. when adding new elements add 2 to `i` inside the loop, loop from right to left or loop over the list and build a new list while doing that.

Comment: Can you show some of the code for how to do that? I am still unsure

Comment: Just add `i += 2;` after you added the 2 new elements.

Comment: Btw, I second what the others said: use curly  braces even for 1-statement blocks since that will prevent a lot of errors. As an example iirc there was a security bug in iOs 2 years ago and the main source for that was missing curly braces and thus someone adding a statement in the wrong place. So you should make using `{ ... }` a good habit.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is better to construct `list` as you go.  Your way of inserting a new element to `list` (which is an `ArrayList` implementation) has two problems:

1. The library is forced to shift everything by one -- this is slow
2. In general changing a list while iterating it is error prone.

I would rewrite the code as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayListInsert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array = new Integer[]{1, 5, 2, 6, 7};

        int smallest = array[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
            if (array[i] < smallest) 
                smallest = array[i];

        String smallestString = String.valueOf(smallest);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (smallestString.equals(String.valueOf(array[i]))) { // be careful!
                list.add("*****"); 
                list.add(Integer.toString(array[i]));
                list.add("*****");
            } else {
                list.add(Integer.toString(array[i]));
            }
        }

        System.out.println("array is\n" + Arrays.deepToString(array));
        System.out.println("list is\n" + list);

//            return smallest;

    }

}
```

The output would be:

```
array is 
[1, 5, 2, 6, 7]
list is
[*****, 1, *****, 5, 2, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Howcome you declare it as `List` but then write `new ArrayList`? Also, what is the difference with `deepToString` and `toString`?

Comment: @J.melb -- This is done deliberately.   You can read, say, "Effective Java, 2nd Ed." by Joshua Bloch to know more details. (Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces)

Comment: @J.melb -- From the book ... "More generally, you should favor the use of interfaces rather than 
classes to refer to objects. If appropriate interface types exist, then 
parameters, return values, variables, and fields should all be declared 
using interface types. The only time you really need to refer to an 
object's class is when you're creating it with a constructor. . . .
If you get into the habit of using interfaces as types, your program will be much more flexible."

Comment: @J.melb -- Arrays.deepToString() is a convenient method.  See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_deeptostring.htm